# Can't access functions in Excel.Application().Workbooks from Python 2.7/3.5: '__ComObject' object has no attribute X

Tags: python, .net, excel, interop, python.net

I am trying to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel from a Python script:

```
import msvcrt
import clr
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel")
import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel as Excel

excel = Excel.ApplicationClass()
excel.Visible = True            # makes the Excel application visible to the user - will use this as True for debug
excel.DisplayAlerts = False     # turns off Excel alerts since I don't have a handler

print ("Excel: " + str(type(excel)))
print ("Workbooks: " + str(type(excel.Workbooks)))
print ("Workbooks count: " + str(excel.Workbooks.Count))
#wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Projects\Experiments\Python\ExcelInterop\Test.xlsx')

print ("Press any key")
msvcrt.getch()
```

Here is the output:

```
C:\Projects\Experiments\Python\ExcelInterop>exceltest.py
Excel: <class 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass'>
Workbooks: <class 'System.__ComObject'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\Experiments\Python\ExcelInterop\exceltest.py", line 12, in <module>
    print ("Workbooks count: " + str(excel.Workbooks.Count))
AttributeError: '__ComObject' object has no attribute 'Count'
```

- I am running in an admin cmd prompt on Windows 10
- I have tried python 2.7 and 3.5 (using py -3 exceltest.py).
- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel is version 15.0.4420.1017 (Office 2013)
- I created a similar .NET console app, which worked fine.
- I used ILDASM to check references from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, and then gacutil -l to double-check that all referenced assemblies are in the GAC.
- Just in case, I copied office.dll, stdole.dll and Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll into the folder where the Python script is running.  These are the assemblies added to the .NET console application build folder if I don't embed the interop types for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
- I have .NET for Python installed for 2.7 and 3.5 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythonnet)

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get to COM objects from pythonnet using reflection currently:

```
clr.AddReference("System.Reflection")
from System.Reflection import BindingFlags

excel.Workbooks.GetType().InvokeMember("Count",
                                       BindingFlags.GetProperty | 
                                       BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
                                       None, excel.Workbooks, None)
```

Here is a wrapper function:

https://gist.github.com/denfromufa/ec559b5af41060c5ac318f7f59d8b415#file-excel_interop_vsto-ipynb